# Strange error: "The input stream is not a valid binary format"

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have the following code to serialize and deserialize data:

```
    static public void Serialize(List<Access> accesos, Stream stream)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, accesos);
    }

    static public List<Access> Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            List<Access> data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<Access>;
            return data;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I serialize an `List<>` to a file, and immediately try to deserialize, the error

> "The input stream is not a valid binary format"

is thrown in `formatter.Deserialize(stream)` line.

On serialization, the stream is being opened with:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(GetConfigurationFilePath(), FileMode.Create);
```

On deserializarion, the stream, is being opened with:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(GetConfigurationFilePath(), FileMode.Open);
```

What may be happening here? the binary format is not changed in any way.

EDIT: This is how I call both static methods:

```
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(GetConfigurationFilePath(), FileMode.Create))
            {
                this.Accesos = frm.Accesos;
                Serializer.Serialize(this.Accesos, stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

            using (Stream stream = File.Open(GetConfigurationFilePath(), FileMode.Open))
            {
                this.Accesos = Serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

    private string GetConfigurationFilePath()
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (path.Last() != '\\')
            path += '\\';
        path += CONFIG_FILE;

        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Strange! Could you confirm `GetConfigurationFilePath` definitely returns the same path & show the full code for serializing/deserializing rather than just the file `File.Open` part?  I'm going to guess the write part doesn't flush/close properly.

Comment: Well lets start with the obvious. Is the stream you're deserializing seeked to the start of the serialized list?

Comment: The path is exactly the same. The stream which I need to deserialize is just opened, so, pointer is at the byte 0

Comment: A long shot: is there a virus checker running on your machine? I have had problems in the past where I wrote code as you describe (a file is created, closed, and immediately re-opened) and an over-aggressive virus checker detected the file creation and immediately locked the file for scanning. The symptom you are describing doesn't sound like it exactly matches that scenario, but it might be worth considering.

Answer (score 5):

> when I serialize a `List<Access>` to a file, and immediately try to deserialize ...

The most likely problem here is that the program has not finished writing to the stream at the time you started deserializing file's content. The formatter did finish its work, but part of the data stays buffered in memory. This may happen because your code does not close the file stream, explicitly or by disposing the stream.

Adding `using` around your streams should fix the problem:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(GetConfigurationFilePath(), FileMode.Create)) {
    ... // Serialization code
}
using (Stream stream = File.Open(GetConfigurationFilePath(), FileMode.Open)) {
    ... // Deserialization code
}
```

Comment: stream is being actually closed. I have updated the question with more code.

Comment: @jstuardo This is very strange: your code follows [a serialization tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list) almost line-for-line, so it should not have any issues. Can you reproduce this behavior in a small, self-contained program with everything hard-coded? I.e. the path, the content of the list, etc.?